# compiling .c in g++ assumes c++ any command line options to treat it as .c

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I have a C++ project [IDE = codelite] which tries to compile .c extention using g++ I want to specify a flag for .c file so that g++ treats it as c

What is the g++ command line option to make it behave as gcc ?

Comment: Don't invoke it as `g++`? It's really that simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either

```
gcc file.c
```

or

```
g++ -x c file.c
```

will do what you want...